# Detecting content based on position in sentence with OpenNLP

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I've successfully used OpenNLP for document categorization and also was able to extract names from trained samples and using regular expressions.

I was wondering if it is also possible to extract names (or more generally speaking, subjects) based on their *position* in a sentence?

E.g. instead of training with concrete names that are know a priori, like `Travel to <START:location> New York </START>`, I would prefer not to provide concrete examples but let OpenNLP decide that anything appearing at the specified position could be an entity. That way, I wouldn't have to provide each and every possible option (which is impossible in my case anyway) but only provide one for the possible surrounding sentence.

Answer (score 1):

that is context based learning and Opennlp already does that. you've to train it with proper and more examples to get good results.

for example, when there is `Professor X` in our sentence, Opennlp trained `model.bin` gives you output `X` as a name whereas when `X` is present in the sentence without professor infront of it, it might not give output `X` as a name.

according to its documentation, give 15000 sentences of training data and you can expect good results.

Comment: The problem is that the sentences always look pretty similar, as in my example. If I come up with 15000 examples of `Travel to ...` I won't need the generic subject detection anymore that I'm after.

Comment: if the training data has more sentences like Travel to <START:Location> xyz <END> so that the model can learn, something like n-grams! then you can expect good results